# F(x) is a 2013 degree function. With integer coefficientsF(0)=1 and f(3) is the divisor of 2013. Compute the largest value for f(3)

Tags: functions

1. List item

The trouble is, how am going to solve this problem without knowing what function is f(x)? All I know is 671 is the largest divisor of 2013.

Comment: Then you're done, aren't you?

Comment: How could this be the largest value for f(x). There must be some limitations the value

Comment: Pick a case - $f$ or $F$, but not both.

Comment: Also, $2013$ is a divisor of $2013$.

Comment: Presumably, it means that $f(x)$ is a 2013 degree polynomial with integer coefficients? Otherwise, $f(3)$ can be anything, and hence it can be 2013.

Comment: Yes, with integer

Comment: $2013 = 3*11*61$ and since $f(3) \mod 3 = 1$ because we know $f(0) = 1$ therefore $f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 +...$ and $f(0) = a_0 = 1$...meanwhile $f(3) = 1 + 3a_1 + 3^2a_2 + ...$ ($1$ plus something divisible by $3$).  So if it's a divisor of $2013$ it certainly cannot be $2013$ itself (since that's divisble by $3$).  It also cannot be $11$, but it _could_ be $61$ since $61 = 3*20 + 1$ and it also could _not_ be $671$ (since this is $3x + 2$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f(x)$ is an integer polynomial with $f(0)=1$, then $f(3)\equiv 1\pmod 3$.

On the other hand, if $d=3k+1$, then $g(x)=(x-3)x^{2012} + kx + 1$ is an integer polynomial of degree $2013$ with $g(0)=1$ and $g(3)=d$.

So you need to find the largest $d\mid 2013$ with $d\equiv 1\pmod{3}$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with mod.

Comment: But I do have some shallow idea how it works.

Comment: It just means that $f(3)-1$ is divisible by $3$ and, later, $d-1$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: Your expression shows that f(x) or 1 divided by 3 has the same remainder.

Comment: I never said that about $f(x)$, only about $f(3)$. $f(x)=1+a_1x+a_2x^2\dots a_{1999}x^{1999}$. So $f(3)$ when divided by $3$ has remainder $1$ because $f(x)-1=x(\dots)$ is always divisible by $x$.